# Custom Commands for Router Device type in Google Home Control Action

Tags: google-home

I am using the device type as a **Router** in order to control my home Router through the Google Home app. I wish to control my router in other ways than what is available in the device traits provided by Google.

For example, I want to implement "*Hey Google, turn on the power saving mode on my Room Router* ".But this command doesn't fall under any of the traits provided by Google i.e NetworkControl, Reboot or softwareUpdate. How can I add the functionality for this command ?

What I have right now is a Home Control project and the node.js code which supports the default traits given by Google.

Do I need to create a new Conversational actions project and program it for all the user commands? Or can I extend my existing project to add the custom command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversational actions are deprecated and will be shut down on June 13, 2023 date, so it’s not a solution anymore. Currently the Google Home ecosystem does not support these use cases at the moment, but internal teams are always working to improve the ecosystem etc.

When building a device, you can mix and match [all available traits](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/traits) on the ecosystem for their router. But you cannot use anything that is not defined.